# error al exportar Exportar excelcon PhPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

Buen dia, estoy tratando de generar un archivo en exel desde el codigo php, el archivo contiene una consulta realizada a una base de datos y dicha consulta la agrega a una hoja de exel el problema que tengo es que al momento de abrir dicho exel me muestra los datos de la siguiente manera:
 [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el codigo con el que cuento es el siguiente

```
<?php
ob_start();
    //Incluimos librería y archivo de conexión
    require '../ACR_pruebas/librerias/PHPExcel.php';
    include("conexion_oracle.php");
     //Consulta
 $sql = oci_parse($conn, "Consulta a base de datos ORACLE"); 
  oci_execute($sql);
    $fila = 0; //Establecemos en que fila inciara a imprimir los datos
    //Objeto de PHPExcel
    $objPHPExcel  = new PHPExcel();
    //Propiedades de Documento
    $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Cruz Roja Seccional Cundinamarca")
    ->setDescription("Reporte de Tablero Pacientes");
    //Establecemos la pestaña activa y nombre a la pestaña
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle("Tablero Pacientes");
    // Encabezados del reporte
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1','UBINOM');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B1','TIP_RESP');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C1','COD_RESPON');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D1','NOM_RESPON');
    //Recorremos los resultados de la consulta y los imprimimos
    while($rows = oci_fetch_array($sql, OCI_ASSOC)){
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$fila, $rows['UBINOM']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$fila, $rows['TIP_RESP']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C'.$fila, $rows['COD_RESPON']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D'.$fila, $rows['NOM_RESPON']);

        $fila++; //Sumamos 1 para pasar a la siguiente fila
    }
    foreach(range('A','AL') as $columnID) {
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($columnID)
            ->setAutoSize(true);
    } 
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-6');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="tablero_pacientes.xls"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
    $objWriter->save('php://output'); 

?>
```

¿Alguno sabe a que se debe el error en el archivo ExcelExcel?